# Using CFD temperature data to generate lighting

Tags: mesh, node-editor, shaders, lighting

I have a VTK file that contains volumetric data on the temperature at different points on a flame. It has been obtained using a CFD simulation, with the file containing different values of temperature at each node in a mesh.

I wish to generate a flame in Blender which has exactly the same temperature distribution as in the above mentioned file. I want each individual control volume in the mesh to be a temperature iso-surface, which generates light using blackbody radiation (basically the blackbody node in Blender).

This is an illustration of the flame temperature distribution (however instead of smooth temperature gradients I have discrete temperature values in a file):

[image]

If there were 2-3 different temperatures, I would have considered using 2-3 blackbody nodes to generate the required lighting. But this object likely contains hundreds of thousands of temperature values. Is there any other way to generate this kind of lighting in Blender?

Comment: Is there any way to convert this to openVDB?

Comment: Please add illustrations and more detail of how the visualized data would look like. We can always use the power of python to automate in blender

Answer (score 0):

How about using [CubeSurfer](https://blender-addons.org/cubesurfer-addon/) addon to calculate the iso surface? `a, b = mciso.isosurface(res, isolevel, ploc, psize, pprop)`